# OnGroupClickListener

Tags: android, expandablelistview

i set on my ExpandableListView OnGroupClickListener. but when i click on expanded group - group at first group  collapsed, **and only after second click** OnGroupClickListener called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. If I click on expanded group. The onGroupClickListener is not called on first click, but on the second !. This happens with version 2.1-update 1. Version 2.2 is working correctly !

To solve this problem you can use:

```
expList.setOnGroupCollapseListener(onGroupCollapseListener);
expList.setOnGroupExpandListener(OnGroupExpandListener);
```

This should work correctly. Worked in my case.

Good Luck !

Comment: setOnGroupCollapseListener and setOnGroupExpandListener dont solves my problem but all the same thank you